# What is wrong with the following haskell typeclass instance?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

```
data II = I Int Int deriving (Show)
instance II Show where
  show I a b = show (a+b)
```

showt.hs:3:2: `show' is not a (visible) method of class`II'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The class name should come before the type in the instance declaration. You also need to remove the `deriving` clause, since you're providing your own instance instead of using one that's automatically derived. You also need to add parenthesis around the single argument to `show`, otherwise it looks like 3 arguments to the parser.

```
data II = I Int Int
instance Show II where
    show (I a b) = show (a+b)
```